# Index 0 Requested, With Size 0

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, android-cursor, cursor-position

I am getting a android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 error when trying list the data from an Sqlite database.  From reading other issues with the same error I can tell that there is a null value for the first record. The resolution seems to be to close off the cursor, but I am already doing this, so this cannot be the cause. Unless I am closing off the cursor incorrectly.  I have post the error I am getting and  the code that I believe is associated to the error.  Any guidance on how to resolve this error would be appreciated.

```
Process: ca.rvogl.tpbcui, PID: 30793
    android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
        at ca.rvogl.tpbcui.Database.DatabaseHelper.getGame(DatabaseHelper.java:445)
        at ca.rvogl.tpbcui.Views.GameActivity.createGame(GameActivity.java:113)
        at ca.rvogl.tpbcui.Views.GameActivity.access$800(GameActivity.java:30)
        at ca.rvogl.tpbcui.Views.GameActivity$7.onClick(GameActivity.java:244)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Code from my DatabaseHelper

```
public Game  getGame(String leagueId, String bowlerId, String seriesId) {
        //Get Readable Database If We Are Not Inserting Anything
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query( Game.TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{Game.COLUMN_ID, Game.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID, Game.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID,
                        Game.COLUMN_SERIES_ID, Game.COLUMN_SCORE, Game.COLUMN_STRIKES, Game.COLUMN_SPARES,Game.COLUMN_SPLITS, Game.COLUMN_SPLIT_CONVERSIONS, Game.COLUMN_OPEN_FRAMES, Game.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP},
                Game.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + "=?" + " AND " +  Game.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID + "=?" + " AND " +  Game.COLUMN_SERIES_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(leagueId), String.valueOf(bowlerId), String.valueOf(seriesId)}, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        //Prepare Game Object
        Game game = new Game(

                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_ID)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_SERIES_ID)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_SCORE)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_STRIKES)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_SPARES)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_SPLITS)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_SPLIT_CONVERSIONS)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_OPEN_FRAMES)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));

        //Close Database Connection
        cursor.close();

        return game;
    }

    public List<Game> getAllGames(String leagueId, String bowlerId, String seriesId) {
        List<Game> games = new ArrayList<>();

        //Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Game.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Game.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + " = '" + leagueId + "'" + " AND " + Game.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID + " = '" + bowlerId + "'" + " AND " + Game.COLUMN_SERIES_ID + " = '" + seriesId + "'" + " ORDER BY " +
                Game.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC";

        try (SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase()) {
            @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery( selectQuery, null );

            //Looping Through All Rows And Adding To The List
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Game game1 = new Game();
                    game1.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_ID ) ) );
                    game1.setLeagueId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID)));
                    game1.setBowlerId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID)));
                    game1.setSeriesId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_SERIES_ID)));
                    game1.setScore(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_SCORE)));
                    game1.setSpares(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_SPARES)));
                    game1.setSplits(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_SPLITS)));
                    game1.setSplitConversions(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_SPLIT_CONVERSIONS)));
                    game1.setOpenFrames(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_OPEN_FRAMES)));
                    game1.setTimestamp(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Game.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));

                    games.add( game1 );
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            //Close Database Connection
            db.close();
        }

        //Return Game List
        return games;
    }
```

Code from Games.java

```
//Inserting New Game In The Database & Refreshing The List
    private void createGame(String leagueId, String bowlerId, String seriesId, String score, String spares, String strikes, String splits, String splitConversions, String openFrames) {
        //Inserting Game In The Database & Getting Newly Inserted Game Id
        long id = db.insertGame(leagueId, bowlerId, seriesId, score, strikes, spares, splits, splitConversions, openFrames);

        //Getting The Newly Inserted Game From The Database
        Game n = db.getGame(leagueId, bowlerId, seriesId);

        if (n != null) {
            //Adding New Game To The Array at Position 0
            gameList.add(0, n);

            //Refreshing The List
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            toggleEmptyGames();
        }
    }

    //Updating Game In The Database & Updating Item In The List By Its Position
    private void updateGame(String score, String strikes, String spares, String splits, String splitConversions, String openFrames, int position) {
        Game n = gameList.get(position);
        //Updating the Game Text
        n.setScore(score);
        n.setStrikes(strikes);
        n.setSpares(spares);
        n.setSplits(splits);
        n.setSplitConversions(splitConversions);
        n.setOpenFrames(openFrames);

        //Updating Game In The Database
        db.updateGame(n);

        //Refreshing The List
        gameList.set(position, n);
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);

        toggleEmptyGames();
    }

    //Deleting Game From SQWLite & Removing The Item From The List By Its Position
    private void deleteGame(int position) {
        //Deleting Game From The Database
        db.deleteGame(gameList.get(position));

        //Removing Game From The List
        gameList.remove(position);
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

        toggleEmptyGames();
    }

    //Opens Dialog With Edit - Delete Options
    private void showActionsDialog(final int position) {
        CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[]{"Edit", "Delete"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose option");
        builder.setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 0) {
                    showGameDialog(true, gameList.get(position), position);
                } else {
                    deleteGame(position);
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

This error is only appearing when I attempt to add another game to the database. When I restart the application the data that was enter appears in the listview, it is however not correct there are missing values from some of the fields.

Revised  Code

```
public Game  getGame(String leagueId, String bowlerId, String seriesId) {
        //Get Readable Database If We Are Not Inserting Anything
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query( Game.TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{Game.COLUMN_ID, Game.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID, Game.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID,
                        Game.COLUMN_SERIES_ID, Game.COLUMN_SCORE, Game.COLUMN_STRIKES, Game.COLUMN_SPARES, Game.COLUMN_SPLITS, Game.COLUMN_SPLIT_CONVERSIONS, Game.COLUMN_OPEN_FRAMES, Game.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP},
                Game.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + "=?" + " AND " + Game.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID + "=?" + " AND " + Game.COLUMN_SERIES_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf( leagueId ), String.valueOf( bowlerId ), String.valueOf( seriesId )}, null, null, null, null );


        // if (cursor.getCount()>0)
        //    cursor.moveToFirst();
        // Log.d("Events",Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()));
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //Prepare Game Object
            Game game = new Game(

                    cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex( Game.COLUMN_ID ) ),
                    cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( Game.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID ) ),
                    cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( Game.COLUMN_BOWLER_ID ) ),
                    cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( Game.COLUMN_SERIES_ID ) ),
                    cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( Game.COLUMN_SCORE ) ),
                    cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( Game.COLUMN_STRIKES ) ),
                    cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( Game.COLUMN_SPARES ) ),
                    cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( Game.COLUMN_SPLITS ) ),
                    cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( Game.COLUMN_SPLIT_CONVERSIONS ) ),
                    cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( Game.COLUMN_OPEN_FRAMES ) ),
                    cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( Game.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP ) ) );

            //Close Database Connection
            cursor.close();

            return game;
        } else {
        }
    }
```

Comment: your `Cursor` is empty (0 rows) - `cursor.moveToFirst()` returns `false` but you dont care

Comment: btw any reason for not using `room architecture component`?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to say.  I am checking if the cursor is not equal to 0 before moving it to the first record.

Comment: I am fairly new to Android application programming, I don't know what room architecture is.

Comment: did you check what does `cursor.moveToFirst()` return?

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room

Comment: i get the following; Index -1 requested, with a size of 0, after putting in this line of code; 'if (cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0)
            cursor.moveToFirst();'

Comment: The problem is that no row was found.

Comment: so what does `cursor.getCount()` return? use `Log.d` to print it out

Comment: I  insert the following; Log.d("Events",Integer.toString(cursor.getCount())); and the logcat shows  D/Events: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is two-fold. First there are no rows being returned by the query which is then not properly checked/handled as you are checking for a **null Cursor** when a Cursor returned from the `query` method **will not be null**. It may be **empty** (cursor.getCount() would return 0).

All of the Cursor `move????` methods return true or false depending on whether or not the move can be made.

As such to correctly handle reading a cursor you should **never** use *(it is useless and as in your case disruptive)* :-

```
if (cursor != null) {
    cursor.moveToFirst(); // (or any move???? method
    ..... Ouch if the Cursor is empty as there will be no first row to extract data from
}
```

rather you should use :-

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    ..... do your stuff here
} else {
    ..... handle no row found here if wanted
}
```

For looping though a Cursor you can use :-

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    .... handle each row here
}
```

If you need to loop through a cursor and handle no rows in the cursor you can use :-

```
if (cursor.getCount() < 1) {
    ..... handle no rows here
}
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    ..... handle each row here
}
```

Noting that in every situation you should close the Cursor when done with it.

Comment: not exactly sure how to format the code it keeps telling me that I need a return statement.  I have posted the revised code  above

Comment: Have a second `return game` after the if clause e.g.  `if { ....... return game; } return game; ` Noting that game will be **null**  when there are no rows.

Comment: I figured it out I used else { return null; }

Comment: Thanks again @MikeT for your assistance.